# How to calculate SSR in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I've trained a linear regression model:

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X, Y)
```

And I want to calculate the three sum of squares SST, SSR and SSRES (a.k.a SSE).

I've calculated the SSE like this: (X is 4 predictive features)

```
y_pred = reg.predict(X)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': Y, 'Predicted':y_pred})
  
print('SS_Res : '+ str(np.sum(np.square(df['Actual']-df['Predicted']))))
```

How do I calculate the SSR (sum of squares regression)? it's supposed to be the sum of the differences between the predicted value by the model and the mean of the dependent variable, but in code how do I put this?

the SST would be easy as soon as I get the SSR, because SST = SSR + SSE

##### EDIT-

Something like this maybe? I'll be glad if anyone can just make sure that I'm right:

```
y_pred = reg.predict(X)
y_mean = np.mean(Y)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': Y, 'Predicted':y_pred, 'mean':y_mean})
  
print('SS_Res : '+ str(np.sum(np.square(df['Actual']-df['Predicted']))))
print('SS_R : '+ str(np.sum(np.square(df['Predicted']-df['mean']))))
```

Comment: Based on this website https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/95/#:~:text=SSR%20is%20the%20%22regression%20sum,%5Chat%7By%7D_i., this looks right